# React Js FormControl control won't toggle checkbox in modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a modal that popsup whenever I edit a specific resource.
It records the changes and updates the application.

From the homepage rfc

```
const [flags,setFlags] = React.useState({})
.
.
.
flags[object1]={flag1: true, flag2:false};
flags[object2]={flag1: true, flag2:false};

<modal
     flags = {flags}
     setFlags = {flags}
..
>
</modal>
```

modal rfc-

```
const modal = ({flags,setFlags....}) =>{

...

const handleFlagChanges = (e, object) =>{
        if(e.target.name=='flag1'){
            flags[object].flag1 = !flags[object].flag1
        }
        else if(e.target.name=='flag2'){
            flags[object].flag2= !flags[object].flag2
        }
        console.log(flags)
}


...
<FormControlLabel
        control={
                <Checkbox
                    name="flag1"
                    checked={flags[object1].flag1}
                    defaultValue={flags[object1].flag1}
                    onClick={(e) => {handleFlagChanges(e, object)}}
                }
                label="Flag"
               />
/>
....

}
```

Problem-
The console log displays the right information (toggling of flag values) but the checkbox does not toggle on screen i.e it does not update the default value.

What I have tried

1. As suggested by some, instead of directly changing the state of the parent component I tried using the set method passed in the child compoment/modal.

```
const handleFlagChanges = (e, object) =>{
        if(e.target.name=='flag1'){
            let temp = flags
            temp[object].flag1 = !temp[object].flag1
            setFlags(temp)
        }
        else if(e.target.name=='flag2'){
            let temp = flags
            temp[object].flag2 = !temp[object].flag2
            setFlags(temp)
        }
        console.log(flags)
}
```

What worked-
Doing exactly as some here suggested. Create a deep copy of the parents state property, manipulate that and use that to update the state

```
const handleFlagChanges = (e, object) =>{
        if(e.target.name=='flag1'){
            let temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(flags))
            temp[object].flag1 = !temp[object].flag1
            setFlags(temp)
        }
        else if(e.target.name=='flag2'){
            let temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(flags))
            temp[object].flag2 = !temp[object].flag2
            setFlags(temp)
        }
        console.log(flags)
}
```

Comment: Updating react state like this `flags[object].flag1 = !flags[object].flag1` is incorrect, use set state method for updating state.

Comment: Edited to accurately the functional component per your comment.

Comment: pass `setFlags` method to modal component and in `handleFlagChanges` method use `setFlags` method to update `flags` state. setFlags({flag1:!flags[object].flag1, flag2:flags[object].flag2})`  and `setFlags({flag1:flags[object].flag1, flag2:!flags[object].flag2})`

Answer (score 1):

Mutating the props directly is an anti-pattern in React. Don’t do that. If you want to then do it by updating the state of the parent component.

Check below mentioned simple implementation.

```js
const ChildComp = ({ state, updateParent }) => {
  return (
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      checked={state} {/* Don't need to set both `checked` & `defaultValue` */}
      onChange={() => updateParent((prev) => !prev)} {/* Execute the handler */}
    />
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  const [state, updateState] = useState(false); // Parent state & handler to update it

  console.log(state);

  return <ChildComp state={state} updateParent={updateState} />;
  // Pass them to the Child
};
```